# Did Theseus kill the Minotaur if Kassandra killed it as well?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

In Assassin's Creed: Odyssey Kassandra fights four monsters from Greek mythology, who guard the artifacts of the Precursor Race. Among them the Minotaur. I am curious, if it is ever explained, how it goes together with the legend of Theseus. He is known to have killed the Minotaur, and he is also mentioned in the game. (You can obtain his armor prior to the fight with the Minotaur, for example.)

Were there originally two Minotaurs, one killed by Theseus and one by Kassandra? Did Theseus lie about killing it? Or is the whole fight just an illusion created by the Piece of Eden, so it is possible to defeat the Minotaur multiple times? (For example that Theseus killed it, but did not collect the Piece of Eden, so the Minotaur "respawned" in the illusory reality after some time?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept in Assassin's creed seems to be that the Precursor objects transform unfortunate people who either stumble across the object, seek it out or slay the corresponding monster.

In the Writhing Dread quest;

> Ligeia is revealed to have slain the Medusa, but, as the creature lay dying the precursor artifact detached itself and fled to her; attaching itself to her and she became the new host - transforming into the Medusa.

Theseus returned from slaying the Minotaur so he escaped this fate. Presumably a random looter in the ensuing 650 years stumbled across the device and became the new minotaur (or one of Theseus' followers).